# Angular 2: Is it bad practice to use ngModel and ngFormControl at same time?

Tags: angular

I would like to use `ngFormControl` for validations purpose only, while binding model directly with `ngModel`, is it considered a bad practice?

Example:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
    <input [ngModel]="name" [ngFormControl]="form.controls.name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I also use that all the time. Sometime we gonna have to use those two at the same time. For an example, we have a drop down component in a model driven form, so we use ngFormControl to bind the value. Also we may need to keep track of the selected item value of the dropdown, so we need to use ngModel.